# Remove "_is1" suffix from Inno Setup AppId

Tags: registry, inno-setup, uninstallation, app-id

When specifying the [`AppId`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid) parameter to an *Inno Setup* script, a `_is1` suffix is automatically added.

I realized that looking at the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Is it possible to disable this suffix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot be removed. It's hardcoded.

See `GetUninstallRegSubkeyName` function of `Projects/Main.pas`:

```pascal
Result := Format('%s\%s_is1', [NEWREGSTR_PATH_UNINSTALL, UninstallRegKeyBaseName]);
```

https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_2_2/Projects/Main.pas#L345-L348